# is there a command line tool to read number of rows and columns of a feather file?

Tags: python, pandas, command-line-interface, feather

I'm working in a project that generates a lot of data, and every month a process writes a csv file with over 6 million records, and then gets converted into a feather file.
There's a need to verify the number of records that the feather file has and compare it to its corresponding csv file.

I have searched and have not found a command line tool for reading the metadata of a feather file, in order to know the number of rows and columns it has.

The closest solution I have is to create a script in Python + Pandas to read the file as a Pandas Dataframe and do `df.shape`

But my feather files are around 6-10 million records, and it is time consuming to load the feather file into the dataframe, and the machine where I have to test it doesn't have a lot of memory or processing power.

```
import pandas as pd

filename = "jan_records.feather"
df = pd.read_feather(filename)
df.shape
```

I appreciate any help on this.